# How to make multiple project share the same node module in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have created many angular projects in my system and every project takes about 400mb size. The projects are taking too much of disk space. On initializing a new project from Angular CLI a different node module folder is created for each project every time. How can I make new projects sharing the same node module package?

Comment: try to look here: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Answer (score 0):

Just try Monorepo approach:
[Angular Monorepo description](https://kgotgit.medium.com/monorepo-pattern-setting-up-angular-workspace-for-multiple-applications-in-one-single-repository-4e14bc0d0cc0)